# Space to be included in POST from text area to PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, I'm trying to write to a file a text written from user. If i put a normal text like "TEST123" it is ok but when i put "TEST 123" it doesnt pass anything. A little help will be appreciated. Thnx

```
<?php
    $filename = 'textfile.txt';
    $content  = $_POST['thedata'] ;
    $handle = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle,'My text is:');
    fwrite($handle,$content);
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

HTML is

```
<form method="post" action="changetxt.php"> 
    <font size"3"><font color="white"><b>Name </b> </font> 
    <div id="dat">
      <textarea name="thedata" id="thedata" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div id="sub" style="position:absolute; left: 25"> 
       <input type="submit" value=" Change Name "> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your calling code

Comment: <font size"3"><font color="white"><b>Name</b> </font>
<div id="dat"><textarea name="thedata" id="thedata" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea></div>
<div id="sub" style="position:absolute; left: 25">
<input type="submit" value=" Change Name ">

Comment: please, put whole html in the answer.

Comment: <form method="post" action="changetxt.php">
<font size"3"><font color="white"><b>Name </b> </font>
<div id="dat"><textarea name="thedata" id="thedata" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea></div>
<div id="sub" style="position:absolute; left: 25">
<input type="submit" value=" Change Name ">
</div>
</form>

Comment: It is just a part of a website it just a form that POST thedata value to changetxt.php

Comment: Please, edit your question and paste the code inside.

Comment: Are you using normal form submission or AJAX to submit the form?

Comment: @Borna Done it I hope its right

Comment: Nothing you've shown will act diferently depending on whether there's a space in the input.

Comment: Sidenote: Technically speaking, you never closed off `<font size"3">` and that's in deprecation/deletion mode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font *"This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."*

Comment: In the code inside question font tag is closed (edited by Riggs), but not in the one he put in the comment...

Comment: Using normal form submission. It works fine when i don't put any spaces in input. When i put a space in, textfile.txt file has just the text "My text is:"

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Using what you say you're using and as per what was posted, produced `My text is:TEST 123` is the result in text file. So... voting to close this.

Comment: ok. you are right. it works fine. I'm trying to make a rsc file to run automatically but if i want to write test 123 it must be in my text: My text is: "test 123" (test 123 is written from user in html) how can put " " to be written to a text file : im trying fwrite($handle,",$content,"); but with no success. please help

Answer (score 0):

I think your question should have been: How do I write quotes to a file?
And the answer would be to put them in the string using escaping (\") in a double quotes string or directly in a single quoted string.

Try:

```
$content = '"' . $_POST['thedata'] . '"';
```

or

```
$content = "\"" . $_POST['thedata'] . "\"";
```

(I would have put this in the comments but I need more reputation...)